# Why does Rubocop prefer `have_received` to `receive`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubocop-rspec

I have tests of the form:

```
expect(ClassA).to receive(:method)
ClassB.perform
```

Rubocop would prefer if I refactored this to use `have_received`, which requires `ClassA` to be mocked. In other words, I need to set up:

```
allow(ClassA).to receive(:method)
ClassB.perform
expect(ClassA).not_to have_received(:method)
```

What's the point? Just following the Arrange Act Assert format?

Comment: As one of the maintainers of rubocop-rspec, I can confirm: the reason is to follow the arrange-act-assert format.

Answer (score 3):

Refactoring to used `have_received` allowed me to move a lot of the set-up into a `before` block, and put tests after the action following the Arrange Ace Assert format.

The code noticeably reads better.

Answer (score 1):

One advantage is: `have_received` allows us to place the expectations after the exercise so our tests would neatly follow the 4 phases test structure:

1. Setup
2. Exercise
3. Expectations
4. Teardown